# SQL Server is creating too many LOB pages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange situation with a SQL Server database where to actual data in the table is roughly *320 MiB*. This is determined by summing up the `DATALENGTH` of all the columns. This will ignore fragmentation, index space and other SQL Server internal overhead. The problem though is that the table is roughly **40 GiB** in size and it's growing at an alarming rate, very disproportionate to the amount of data in bytes or rows that was inserted.

I used the `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` function to look at the physical data and the roughly 40 GiB of data is tied up in `LOB_DATA`.

The most of the 320 MiB that makes up the table contents is of type `ntext`. Now, my question is how come SQL Server has allocated 40 GiB of `LOB_DATA` when there's only roughly 310 MiB `ntext` data.

Will the problem go away if we convert the column to `nvarchar(max)`? Are there any storage engine specifics regarding `ntext` and `LOB_DATA` that is causing the `LOB_DATA` pages to not be reclaimed? Why is it groing at a so disproportionate rate with regards to the amount of changes that are being made?

Comment: Seems odd. What is the table definition including indexes? What is the pattern of usage of this table? Are the `ntext` columns frequently updated for example? What is the actual output of `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`?

Comment: I don't have access to the database right now... that said, roughly 200 new rows of  `ntext` data in the range of KBytes results in huge database growths (GBytes). The `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` can be summarized as 99.99999% of pages allocated in `LOB_DATA`. Apparently the situation was remedied by using `DBCC CLEANTABLE` but that does not really explain why this happened in the first place.

Comment: Is the table a heap or a CI? What were the values for record count, ghost record count, avg record size, avg page space used etc?

Comment: It's a CI, well the `avg page space used` was `0.8%` but after `DBCC CLEANTABLE` most things look normal.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/) using `nvarchar(max)` is not going to solve this problem. It depends on the size of the text you store whether it is stored `IN_ROW_DATA` or in `LOB_DATA`.